# Using awk to parse AIX's lsuser output in stanza format

Tags: text-processing, awk, aix

I'm creating a simple awk script to parse AIX's `lsuser -f ALL` output and return information in one line. A sample of the output is something like this.

```
root:
    id=0
    pgrp=something
    groups=something
    home=/
    shell=/usr/bin/csh
    auditclasses=general
    login=true
    su=false
```

Here is my code so far:-

```
$1 ~ /[^=]:[ ]*$/ {sub(/:/,"",$1);printf $1" ";FS="="}
$1 ~ /login/         {printf $2" "}
$1 ~ /su/     {printf $2" "}
$1 ~ /account_locked/         {printf $2" "}
$1 ~ /time_last_login/     {print $2}
```

The script does not work well with fields that does not exist for certain ID such as `time_last_login` because some user may not have logged in before. Example as per below.

```
root something ALL false 1360813178
**daemon staff ALL true sysadm1 something ALL false 1352015794**
sysadm2 staff ALL true 1352015794
```

sysadm1 line should be in a new line. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a variable e.g. `user` when you get to the `user:` line. Thus
if it **is** set print a newline before user name, else not, and skip print of newline under `time_last_login`.

If one or more fields could be missing you would probably use an array and print after each iteration of user and add an `END{}` for last.

This way you can print e.g. `N/A` for missing fields.

Alternatively use an array to specify which fields you want to print.

Example (with both):

```
function prnt_user_data(arr, prnt) {
    printf("\nAlternative 1:\n")
    for (p in prnt) {
        printf("%s ", prnt[p] in arr ? arr[prnt[p]] : "N/A")
    }
    printf("\nAlternative 2:\n")
    printf(\
    "%s %s %s %s\n",
    "user"            in arr ? arr["user"] : "N/A",
    "su"              in arr ? arr["su"] : "N/A",
    "account_locked"  in arr ? arr["account_locked"] : "N/A",
    "time_last_login" in arr ? arr["time_last_login"] : "N/A" \
    );
    delete arr;
}

BEGIN {
    FS="=|[ \t]*"
    prnt_flds["01"]="user";
    prnt_flds["02"]="su";
    prnt_flds["03"]="account_locked";
    prnt_flds["04"]="time_last_login";
}
NF == 0 {next}
NF == 3 {
    user_data[$2]=$3;
}
NF == 1 && /:[ ]*$/{
    if("user" in user_data)
        prnt_user_data(user_data, prnt_flds)
    user_data["user"]=substr($1, 1, length($1) - 1);
}
END {
    if("user" in user_data)
        prnt_user_data(user_data, prnt_flds)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sukminder for the explanation. I understand better now.